# Async/Await in fetch() how to handle errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I have stripe async code in my React app, and trying to add error handling in my code but have no idea how to handle it. i know how to do it with .then() but async/await is new to me

**EDITED**

added .catch() i got errors in network tab in response tab.
but i can log it to console?

```
    submit = async () => {
    const { email, price, name, phone, city, street, country } = this.state;
    let { token } = await this.props.stripe
      .createToken({
        name,
        address_city: city,
        address_line1: street,
        address_country: country
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      });

    const data = {
      token: token.id,
      email,
      price,
      name,
      phone,
      city,
      street,
      country
    };

    let response = await fetch("/charge/pay", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
    });
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok)
      this.setState({
        complete: true
      });
  };
```

thanks

Comment: What errors do you want to handle? Please show us how you would have done it with `then`.

Comment: @MattWay Rather the reverse - how to *catch* in `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: please take a look updated question

Comment: In the catch part, try console.log(error). Just a suggestion, try it out.

Comment: console.log at second .catch gives me in network tab and response tab i have {"name":"Name field is required","email":"Email is invalid","phone":"Phone field is required","city":"City field is required","street":"Street field is required","country":"Country field is required"} which is ok but how to access it?? to display on frontend?

Answer (score 74):

Fetch detects only network errors. Other errors (401, 400, 500) should be manually caught and rejected.

```
await fetch("/charge/pay", headers).then((response) => {
    if (response.status >= 400 && response.status < 600) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }
    return response;
}).then((returnedResponse) => {
   // Your response to manipulate
   this.setState({
     complete: true
   });
}).catch((error) => {
  // Your error is here!
  console.log(error)
});
```

If you are not comfortable with this limitation of fetch, try using axios.

Comment: What do you mean by "*manually catched and rejected.*"? Please give an example.

Comment: Fetch doesnt reject `response.status >= 400 && response.status < 600`. It considers them as exceptions, not errors. By rejecting manually, I meant the else part where we throw catch the exception and throw the error.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the `if (response.ok)` check in your code (which imo is better than comparing `response.status`). I must have mistaken the first `then` invocation for the options argument like in the snippets in the question and other answers.

Comment: Thanks and true, that's even more cleaner approach. I just wanted to convey fetch's response handling with the code I wrote.

Comment: How do I get the errormessage returned from the server?

Comment: In catch, you can read the error messages from the server.  If your server is returning you errors which you can see in  network -> response tab, you can find it in: `error.response.data`

Comment: In given example both success and failure is handled using promise. What is the point of having `await` in the beginning? I don't change anything and can be safely removed.

Comment: @Avanthika do you have same solution for `async await` without using `.then()`

Comment: Don't use both async/await and promise patterns (`.then`). For good `fetch` error handling practices, I recommend reading https://web.dev/fetch-api-error-handling/

Answer (score 27):

```
var handleError = function (err) {
    console.warn(err);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({
        code: 400,
        message: 'Stupid network Error'
    }));
};

var getPost = async function () {

    // Get the post data
    var post = await (fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5').catch(handleError));

    // Get the author
    var response = await (fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + post.userId).catch(handleError));

       if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(response);
        }

};
```

Answer (score 13):

You can either use `try`/`catch` just like normal, imperative programming:

```
try {
    let response = await fetch("/charge/pay", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
} catch(error) {
    // Error handling here!
}
```

Or you can mix-and-match `.catch()` just like you do with promises:

```
let response = await fetch("/charge/pay", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Error handling here!
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first example will not catch the request error.

Comment: The first example does not catch errors.

Comment: The first example does catch the same error that would also be handled in the second example. But if the url is responding eg. with a 404 no error will be handled. This is because fetch is successful even if the returned response from the server is telling you that the resource is not found.

Answer (score 5):

This works if server returns `{ message: "some error" }` but I'm trying to get it to support `res.statusText` too:

```
        const path = '/api/1/users/me';
        const opts = {};
        const headers = {};
        const body = JSON.stringify({});
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (token) {
          headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }

        try {
            const res = await fetch(path, {
                method: opts.method || 'GET',
                body,
                headers
            });

            if (res.ok) {
                return await (opts.raw ? res.text() : res.json());
            }

            const err = await res.json();

            throw new Error(err.message || err.statusText);
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
```

Comment: This works & is clear.

Comment: Thanks. Its the best I've come up with so far. Add some more.

Comment: This does not work for NetworkError errors.  You'll see error logs in the console complaining about uncaught errors.

Comment: How to fix it then?

Comment: Best answer found so far, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
try {
  const response = await fetch('/api/getdata')
  if(response.ok) {
    // do sth if success
  } else {
    throw new Error(JSON.stringify({ code: response.status, message: response.statusText }))
  }
} catch (error) {
  alert(error)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, it is always best  to explain your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your await with try catch.

```
try {
    let response = await fetch("/charge/pay", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: still can't get error on frontend... my object with errors is present in network tab...

Comment: This won't work.  Tried this, and still saw uncaught errors.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 async function loginWithRedirect(payload: {
        username: string;
        password: string;
    }) {
      const resp = await (await fetch(`${env.API_URL}/api/auth/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        credentials: "include",
      })).json();
      if (resp.error) {
        dispatch({type: "ERROR", payload: resp.error.message});
      } else {
        dispatch({type: "LOGIN", payload: resp});
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If response.ok is false you can throw an error then chain catch method after calling your function as follows

```
async function fetchData(){
    const response = await fetch("/charge/pay", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    if(!response.ok){
        const message = `An error occured: ${response.status}`;
        throw new Error(message);
    }
    
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

fetchData()
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Answer (score -1):

I write promise function for using fetch in async await.

```
const promisyFetch = (url, options) =>
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
fetch(url, options)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => resolve(result))
  .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

By the way i can use it easly in async with try catch

```
const foo = async()=>{
try {
    const result = await promisyFetch('url' requestOptions)
    console.log(result)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
}
```

It was simple example, you could customize promisyFetch function and request options as you wish.