# correct way to catch error from backend in a async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The `response.json()` from a backend is an data object which can be if request is OK:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "p2",
            "name": "My Second Book",
            "price": 8.98,
            "quantity": 2,
            "totalPrice": 17.96
        },
        {
            "id": "p1",
            "name": "My First Book",
            "price": 6.99,
            "quantity": 3,
            "totalPrice": 20.97
        }
    ],
    "totalQuantity": 5
}
```

Or if  there any error, it responses with this object:

```
{
    "code": 404,
    "description": "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
    "message": "Not Found"
}
```

The function for fetching request exports dispatch result.

```
export function fetchCartData() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/cart");
      const result = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(result);
        throw new Error(result);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      }
    };
    try {
      const cartData = await fetchData();
      dispatch(cartActions.replaceCart(cartData));
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(error);
      dispatch(
        uiActions.showNotification({
          status: "error",
          title: "Error!",
          message: "Fetching cart data failed!",
        })
      );
    }
  };
}
```

The goal of `fetchData` function nested is sending `GET` request to API, store OK or not OK response in constant `result` and pass it to `try-catch` for handle response or error.

if `response is OK` in `fetchData` function, `try` dispatch it, but when `response is not OK` the object result brings information such `message: Not Found` which I want to pass to `catch(error)` for replacing in message into 'dispatch(uiActions.showNotification({message:` key.

I tried returning `result` when response is not OK but it still does not pass object to `catch`, for example:

```
if (!response.ok) {
   console.log(result);
   return result;
   }
```

Comment: `response.ok` isn't going to work here, you'll need to check `response.status`. See: [Async/Await in fetch() how to handle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163952/async-await-in-fetch-how-to-handle-errors)

Comment: actually `response.ok` is working, the object result pass one function up to `dispatch function`. it is part of "@reduxjs/toolkit"

Comment: Oh, you're right, I apologize. I can't reproduce though, with a simplified version of your code. Does the console.log above the dispatch in the catch block never get hit?